# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown causes screen flickering

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have added following script in my page :

```
 1- MultiSelection.js
 2- bootstrap.min.js
 3- MultipleSelection.css
```

and I have specified my control like this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBoxProductType" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">                                            
</asp:ListBox>
```

and javascript:

```
 $(function () {
            $('[id*=listBoxProductType]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                nonSelectedText: "P Type",
                selectAllText: "Select All",
                numberDisplayed: 1
            });
        });
```

This control is working as expected, but whenever I am reloading the page It is flickering for few seconds. I have come through solutions that suggest to make display none and I tried that too. But no luck. Can someone suggest me better ways to do this? Please see picture for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with `display: none; visibility: hidden and opacity: 0;` once select is render remove all CSS properties